# Division by Zero Error in Crosstab Query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, divide-by-zero

I've been successfully running this code for a while now using an abbreviated set of data of approximately 15 stocks worth of historical stock prices (example: http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=goog).  I just scaled up the amount of data to approximately 6,000 stocks (920,570 records in my `DataTable`) and now I am having some problems.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub Update_Quarterly_Growth_Rates()
    ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Updating Quarterly Growth Rates"
    con.Open()
    Try
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Stock_Price_with_qtr AS SELECT Historical_Stock_Prices.*, Year([Date]) AS [Year], Switch(Month([Date])<4,1,Month([Date])<7,2,Month([Date])<10,3,True,4) AS Qtr FROM Historical_Stock_Prices", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Dim cmda As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE Stock_Price_with_qtr", con)
        cmda.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim cmdb As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Stock_Price_with_qtr AS SELECT Historical_Stock_Prices.*, Year([Date]) AS [Year], Switch(Month([Date])<4,1,Month([Date])<7,2,Month([Date])<10,3,True,4) AS Qtr FROM Historical_Stock_Prices", con)
        cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Try

    Try
        Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Qtr_Dates AS SELECT Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Year], Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr, Min(Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Date]) AS Qtr_Start, Max(Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Date]) AS Qtr_End FROM Stock_Price_with_qtr GROUP BY Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Year], Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr", con)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Dim cmd1a As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE Qtr_Dates", con)
        cmd1a.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim cmd1b As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Qtr_Dates AS SELECT Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Year], Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr, Min(Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Date]) AS Qtr_Start, Max(Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Date]) AS Qtr_End FROM Stock_Price_with_qtr GROUP BY Stock_Price_with_qtr.Ticker, Stock_Price_with_qtr.[Year], Stock_Price_with_qtr.Qtr", con)
        cmd1b.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Try

    Try
        Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS SELECT Qtr_Dates.Ticker, Qtr_Dates.[Year], Qtr_Dates.Qtr, (([Close_Prices]![Close]/[Open_Prices]![Open])-1)*100 AS Growth_Rate FROM (Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) AND (Open_Prices.[Date] = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)) INNER JOIN Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker) AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.[Date])", con)
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        Dim cmd2a As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("DROP PROCEDURE Quarterly_Growth_Rates", con)
        cmd2a.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim cmd2b As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS SELECT Qtr_Dates.Ticker, Qtr_Dates.[Year], Qtr_Dates.Qtr, (([Close_Prices]![Close]/[Open_Prices]![Open])-1)*100 AS Growth_Rate FROM (Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) AND (Open_Prices.[Date] = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)) INNER JOIN Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker) AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.[Date])", con)
        cmd2b.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Try
    Close()
    ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Load_Quarterly_Growth_Rates()
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("TRANSFORM First(y.Growth_Rate) AS FirstOfGrowth Select y.Ticker FROM Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS y GROUP BY y.Ticker ORDER BY y.Year & '-' & y.Qtr DESC PIVOT y.Year & '-' & y.Qtr", con)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
    Dim da As New DataTable
    da.Load(reader)
    DataGridView_Quarterly_Growth_Rates.DataSource = da
    reader.Close()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

When I try to display the query by loading it into a `DataGridView`, I get a `Division by zero` error.  I'm not quite sure where to go from here.  I guess I would like to disregard any results that are affected by dividing by zero and just return a blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your growth calculations, use something like

```
IIf([Open_Prices]![Open] <> 0,
    (([Close_Prices]![Close]/[Open_Prices]![Open])-1)*100,
    null
   )
```

instead of

```
(([Close_Prices]![Close]/[Open_Prices]![Open])-1)*100
```

This checks for `0` and avoids executing the division if the denominator would be `0`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and used this code `Dim cmd2b As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("CREATE PROC Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS SELECT Qtr_Dates.Ticker, Qtr_Dates.[Year], Qtr_Dates.Qtr, IIf([Open_Prices]![Open] <> 0, AS Growth_Rate FROM (Historical_Stock_Prices AS Open_Prices INNER JOIN Qtr_Dates ON (Open_Prices.Ticker = Qtr_Dates.Ticker) AND (Open_Prices.[Date] = Qtr_Dates.Qtr_Start)) INNER JOIN Historical_Stock_Prices AS Close_Prices ON (Qtr_Dates.Ticker = Close_Prices.Ticker) AND (Qtr_Dates.Qtr_End = Close_Prices.[Date])", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
       cmd2b.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: I got an message saying that one or more errors occurred.

Comment: @gromit1 You are missing something where there are the three dots at `IIf([Open_Prices]![Open] <> 0, ... AS Growth_Rate`. Note that my proposed replacement text is four lines in my original, you seem to have replaced the original text with just the first line of it. (It is not necessary to put the test on several lines, just makes the code more readable.)